# How would I get the parent height to increase?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I am creating a document upload system and want to have rows of all the documents that have been uploaded with the last row being the "add another document" row. Currently, the list container with the rows is not expanding and instead just reducing the height of the items in the list. Instead, I am trying to get the parent height to expand to include all the items in the list. Any help is appreciated!

```
￼import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Upload extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{'height': '100vh', 'display': 'flex', 'justifyContent': 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <div style={{'flex': 0.8, maxWidth: 800, flexGrow: 1, 'borderRadius': 10, 'boxShadow': '0px 0px 10px #82828240', 'paddingLeft': 50, 'paddingRight': 50, 'paddingTop': 100, 'paddingBottom': 100, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Document upload</h2>
                            <p>Some subtitle placeholder</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div style={{'display': 'flex','flexDirection': 'column', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                            <div style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            <div style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 0, backgroundColor: 'blue', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}} />
                            {/* <button type='button' style={{'flex': 1, flexShrink: 0, 'borderStyle': 'dashed'}} onClick={() => this.input.click()}/>
                            <input id='file-upload' type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} ref={(input) => this.input = input}/> */}
                        </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 80%` and change the `li` to a `div`.

Comment: The more rows I add the smaller the items get, which makes sense but instead I am trying to get the parent div to increase in height. https://puu.sh/DusZp/2f4992c5c9.png

Comment: One sec, going to prototype it :)

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing <li> with <div>s inside of it rather than <div> with <div>s inside or <ul> with <li>s inside?

Comment: No reason, been trying out other methods but have not tried the <li> inside the <ul>

Comment: I'm prototyping it with HTML (removed <button> and <input>) and so far it's working for me. What are you doing to expand the items in the list? Could you put a border around the parent <li> element and show a screenshot of what it looks like when you expand the items?

Comment: Ok so, it depends on what you're really looking to do. Do you want the parent container to be only as big as it needs to contain the items? If so, ignore my previous comment about flex-grow, and just remove the 'height: 80%' on the outer <div>

Comment: So I want the parent to dynamically change in height as more rows are added. I removed the 80% height and flex-grow but the li view disappears. I updated my code

Comment: Change that <li> to a <div> :) then it won't disappear

Comment: yep the div is now expanding relative to item count and the parent is changing height as well. However, the items are not showing.

Comment: The parent is expanding relative to the item count, but the items aren't showing? What's inside the parent container now that is increasing its size if the items aren't there?

Comment: The background color is not showing (blue). I checked the console and I do not see any conflicting constraints. https://puu.sh/Duv2d/d6d095fda5.png

Comment: Are the top/bottom margins still there and just the blue background missing?

Comment: Is the code in the original question up to date with what you have now? (ie. did you replace the <li> with <div>?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193598/discussion-between-joethemow-and-gkeenley).